# How do I configure Snowsql to automatically run a sql script as soon as it connects Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I setup my snowsql in mac and it works fine for general sql commands. What I'm trying to achieve here is to config the snowsql automatically run a pre-configured sql script upon the connection is established.

It's similar to Aginity's pre-execute script configuration in the connection property page. [image]

Appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Create batch file , to wrap up snowsql run which will connect to SNowflake and subsequent run command to run the default sql script.